# How to populate non-entity POJO class by executing dynamic query using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ibatis

I'v got a task to migrate certain part of a project from iBatis to Hibernate. I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer (
  country VARCHAR(3)   NOT NULL,
  code    VARCHAR(2)   NOT NULL,
  name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (country, code)
);

CREATE TABLE model (
  country           VARCHAR(3)   NOT NULL,
  manufacturer_code VARCHAR(2)   NOT NULL,
  code              VARCHAR(2)   NOT NULL,
  name              VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (country, manufacturer_code, code),
  CONSTRAINT fk__model_manufacturer FOREIGN KEY (country, manufacturer_code) REFERENCES manufacturer (country, code)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I created entity classes and repositories for the manufacturer and model. It works so far. But now I need to implement this dynamic query (iBatis mapper @Select):

```
SELECT country, code, name,
<if test="criteria.text != null">,ARRAY_TO_JSON(regexp_matches(name, #{criteria.text},'i')) AS match</if>
FROM manufacturer
WHERE UPPER(country) = UPPER(#{countryCode})
<if test="criteria.text != null"> AND name ~* #{criteria.text}</if>
ORDER BY name
</script>
```

It's used for searching manufacturer name by a regular expression. The result contains manufacturer code and name and also details about regexp matches. The result is stored within non-entity POJO class through iBatis result map.

Could you please advise how to achieve this using JPA? Or would you recommend another way how to achive this? How would you resolve such task?
Please elaborate a bit more in detail, I'm a learning novice on this field. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm slowly working on a migration in the other direction.